# Foundation accordion all active or expanded on page load

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, zurb-foundation

I am having issues implementing the foundation accordion.  The issue seems to be when the page loads all content is active or expanded.  However, when the page loads only one accordion content should be active which you denote with

```
<li class="active">
```

Oddly enough, after the page loads and you click an accordion title the JS responds and makes only the active div display and all other divs disappear.

I used this topic thread here to implement accordion to my site : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/foundation-framework-/alYolSjS8w8.

Here is a link to the broken accordion:  http://rppdesigns.com/dev/pennProp_dev/index.php/home/contact.

Comment: You include `app.js` *before* jQuery.  Try moving it after.  If that doesn't fix your issue, then please post the code that should be hiding the other accordions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your code after the accordion is loaded:

```
$(".active").trigger('click');
```

Comment: I put that in after calling the accordion however it didn't change.  I am starting to think this is my own doing, I have a jquery loading gif while the page loads then a show on all divs.

` $(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();       
       $('div.container div').show();   
  
  
   });`

i thought this only affected the first tier of divs however it seems like it drills through to the nested ones as well.  is there a work around for this?

Comment: Put that `.trigger` after the `$("div.container div").show()`

Comment: thank you looks like I have to read up on trigger, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Make a class called whatever ie .disguise

```
.disguise{display:none;}
```

apply that to whatever non-actives

add in the active a !important `display: inline;`

you just trumped the bug...

Answer (score 0):

Using Foundation 5.x, this is the only way I was able to get it to work:

```
$(document).foundation({
    accordion: {
        // allow multiple accordion panels to be active at the same time
        multi_expand: true
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    // Expand unopened sections
    $('a[aria-expanded="false"]').click();
});
```